# How to return custom exception message to Ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I want to return a specific message on error of an ajax request.

```
[WebMethod]
public static AjaxReturnObject SubmitWager(string token, string track, string race, string amount, string pool, string runners)
{
    try
    {
        var serviceReturn = Services.Account.SubmitWager("", track, race, pool, amount, runners);
        return new AjaxReturnObject(serviceReturn.AccountToken, serviceReturn.Payload);
    }
    catch (CustomServiceException<string> e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Debugging says that it hits my catch when I need it to, but when I look at the xhr within my jquery ajax call it ALWAYS says "There was an error processing the request."

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            log(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

How can I get my desired message to comeback to the ajax call under xhr.responseText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the better route would be is to define the success callback of the AJAX request with code that checks a success flag:

**c#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static AjaxReturnObject SubmitWager(string token, string track, string race,   string amount, string pool, string runners)
{
try
{
    var serviceReturn = Services.Account.SubmitWager("", track, race, pool, amount, runners);
    return new AjaxReturnObject(serviceReturn.AccountToken, serviceReturn.Payload);
}
catch (CustomServiceException<string> e)
{
    return new AjaxReturnObject(0, e.Message();
}
}
```

---

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.AccountToken == 0) {
      // There was an error 
      log(data.Payload);
    }
    else {
      // your code
    }
  }
});
```

I offer this alternative because I'm not sure that if you throw an error in the server side code, that the function returns anything back. That error you're receiving, is client side, the `error` callback really refers to whether or not the request could be made.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of doing that. I feel it defeats some of the purpose of even having an 'error' handler for the ajax call, but it may be my only option.

Comment: I feel like the bigger point of the error callback on the ajax call are for things like connectivity problems, if the web service is unavailable, or in cases like this internal service error. But, I'd say the problem is that it doesn't receive data back other than "it didn't work"

Comment: It bothers me that in most cases for my purposes, whether its connectivity issues or invalid data issues, the response is generally the same for all those situations. Which leaves me to write code like:

    success: function (data) {
    if (data.AccountToken == 0) { doError(); }
    else {
      // your code
    }
  },
  error: doError
}

function doError(){......}

Answer (score 4):

Try just `Throw` instead of `Throw new` in the catch block. and once u parse the XHR.responseText, the exception message will be contained in "Message"
For ex:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       //... other parameters
       error: function(XHR, errStatus, errorThrown) {
             var err = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
             errorMessage = err.Message;
       }
});
```