# Retrieve exception message on ajax calls

Tags: exception, asp.net-ajax

I'm making from client different ajax calls to web methods in my page. Some of the methods will throw in some cases exceptions. I want to be able to show the message of the exception to the user.

I have found that I can use "`<customerrors mode= Off>`" but also this approach [How to return custom exception message to Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128470/how-to-return-custom-exception-message-to-ajax-call)

The second one seems like a lot of extra coding in JS,  but I don't know if the first is acceptable in a production environment.

Could you please advice me on this!
Thank you.

EDIT: Example: I'm adding a new user and validation in my DB says it is already there, I want to be able to show the message in a div/span/label (in a jquery dialog)  but in the same page and without page postback.

Answer (score 0):

Create One Error.aspx page and write the following code in global.asax code file.

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

                string ErrorMessage = Server.GetLastError().ToString();
                Session[ErrorMessage] = ErrorMessage;
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");   
    }
```

Write Session[ErrorMessage] on your Error.aspx page.

You will get exception message whenever exception occur in web application and it will show on Error.aspx page.

Comment: I want to avoid redirecting to another page.Example: I'm adding a new user and validation in my DB says it is already there, I want to be able to show the message in a div/span/label whatever but in the same page and without page postback